# Headphones connected to Scarlett 2i2 sound poor versus direct synth connection

Tags: synthesizer, audio

I connected the main/outputA Left & Right Channels of my DSI Prophet X synth to a Scarlett 2i2 (2nd Gen) via two TS cables. When I plug headphones (no adapter) into the Scarlett's headphone jack the quality is significantly worse and muddied relative to plugging directly into the synth.

Would greatly appreciate any help!
[image]

Comment: Did you check levels that it isn't distorting? How are the channels 1/2 panned - do you get stereo sound? In what way is the sound worse, how would you characterize it?

Comment: The sound is a bit muddied an unclear. It is not static or crackle. Several notes at the same time do not come through crisply. No red clipping indicators and varying gain does not change quality. Not sure how the channel is panned I suppose it is the default setting.

Comment: What are the buttons on the Focusrite set to? Line/instr, gain, 48v, direct monitor, headphone volume?

Comment: Both inputs on Instrument, direct monitor on, headphone volume 7, Gains are on 3

Comment: Sounds very flat and dull, less brilliance

Comment: Well, the synth outputs are unbalanced and the Focusrite inputs are balanced, so pseudo-balanced cables will lower the noise floor by 6dB compared to mono cables. But mono cables shouldn't make the sound "flat and dull". Maybe the synth isn't sending the same signal to headphones and line output? Like sending different layers to output A and B, or without effects or something?

Comment: According to the Sound On Sound review, output A has the sound of all the layers, but only if nothing is plugged into output B. (Maybe the outputs can also be assigned in the synth's settings, and they're not set to the default?)

Comment: Just checked, output B set to off. The sound out the interface sounds Mono I think

Comment: The direct monitor output on the Focusrite is indeed mono (which makes sense if you connect e.g. a guitar and a microphone). https://support.focusrite.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360000706625-How-to-use-the-Direct-Monitor-feature-on-the-Scarlett-Solo-2i2-and-iTrack-Solo To monitor in stereo, use the monitoring loopback function in the recording software.

Comment: I'll record in my Daw and playback to see if it improves

Comment: Playback seems to sounds better but I need to trade a break to confirm, my ears can't tell anything anymore ; _) Thank both of you for the help!